# Identify paid Features in Davinci-16_ Free

Tags: davinci-resolve, freeware

I would like to switch to latest Davinci-16_ Free(Version 16.2.7.010)  but on trying some essential ResovleFx effects like film grain,analog grain etc , Davinci shows a switch to paid version message prompt and when rejected it simply shows the Davinci logo overlay than the actual effect.

However unlike other softwares,Davinci doesn't provide any indication in the software itself (other than having to go through their forum to understand the differences [here](https://forum.blackmagicdesign.com/viewtopic.php?f=21&t=92916)).

It doesn't give much confidence if one were to make a switch from a paid software to simply find that essential parts of the freeware are locked.

How does one identify which effects and other features are paid and can these paid effects be recreated in Fusion?

[image: logo]

Comment: here are some videos / articles that might help you find out which effects are free https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cI-T3Pl9dPs
https://motionarray.com/learn/davinci-resolve/davinci-resolve-price-free-vs-studio/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This an older document (v15), but I believe that most of the Free v/s Paid feature list is still valid: https://documents.blackmagicdesign.com/SupportNotes/DaVinci_Resolve_15_Feature_Comparison.pdf